# Can an abstract class have only method signatures without implementation like interfaces?

Tags: c#, java, .net, oop

Like Interfaces, can an abstract class have only method signatures without implementation? If yes:

1. How do abstract classes differ from interfaces?
2. How can another class, which has an abstract class as its base class, implement the body of the base class methods?

Comment: I have a confusion on whether implementation is optional or compulsory.

Comment: Do you mean `Can an abstract class have "only method signature" as interfaces without implementation?` or `Can an abstract class "have only method signature" as interfaces without implementation?`? I decided to delete my answer because of the confusing title.

Comment: @AlvinWong: That is what he means, and it is really confusing things due to the way it is worded at the moment..

Comment: You guys have confused me further. I believe I meant the latter one.

Comment: The rule of thumb: always use interfaces unless you _have_ to use abstract classes. Interfaces allow "multiple inheritance", you can create objects that talk multiple interfaces. Abstract classes make things more messy but can sometimes be useful when it is convenient to implement _some_ methods but not all of the abstract class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An abstract class can contain implementations, but it doesn't have to. This is one thing that makes it different from interfaces.

```
abstract class classA
{
    abstract public void MethodA();

    public void MethodB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is MethodB inside ClassA");
    }
}

class classB : classA
{

    public override void MethodA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is MethodA inside class B");
    }
}
```

If you implement a method in the abstract base class and want to be able to override it later, you need to declare the method as virtual.

```
virtual protected void MethodC(){
  //this can be overridden
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Like Interfaces, can an abstract class have only method signature without implementation? If yes:

Yes, but can also have implementation ...

You can also have method implementation in the `abstract` class unlike `interfaces`, but you can not create an instance of an `abstract class`

> [Interfaces and Abstract Classes](http://en.csharp-online.net/Interfaces_and_Abstract_Classes)
>
> [Abstract Class versus Interface](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11155/Abstract-Class-versus-Interface)

Comment: Wrong answer..An abstract class can have only method signature without implementation..

Comment: @Asif If "Can Have" than how you answered "No". This means an abstract class must have implementation.

Comment: @user935439: I assume he was confused by the wording in the question (as was I).  This is still correct even if the "No" is wrong. It is the only answer which clearly states that an abstract class can contain both implementation and abstract methods

Comment: I think you guys are confused with my wording. please have a look at the update.

Comment: @user935439, An Abstract class can have method implementation,

Answer (score 2):

in Java:

q1: The abstract class can contain method definitions AND normal methods while an interface cannot.

q2: from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

```
//this is the abstract class
public abstract class GraphicObject {
  abstract void draw();
}

//this is the implementation 
class Rectangle extends GraphicObject {
  void draw() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Like Interfaces, can an abstract class have only method signature without implementation?

**Yes**. Abstract class **can have** method implementation.

> How it differs from Interface?

Variables declared in an interface is by default final. An  abstract class may contain non-final variables.

Members of a interface are public by default. An abstract class can have the usual flavors of class members like private, protected, etc..

Interface is absolutely abstract and cannot be instantiated; An abstract class also cannot be instantiated, but can be invoked if a main() exists.

In comparison with abstract classes, interfaces are slow as it requires extra indirection.

Refer the following links:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1240708.aspx/1

http://java.sys-con.com/node/36250

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11155/Abstract-Class-versus-Interface

Comment: Don't use so much bold please. And use the blockquote markup instead of the code one when you're highlighting quotes.

Comment: Can't you have an abstract class without implementation?

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst Yes. We can have an abstract class without implementation.

Comment: @Kirk Broadhurst yes you can have an abstract class without implementation

Comment: @MaVRoSCy This answer says **no** we can't.

Comment: Is this from C# or Java perspective? Is the concept of "Optional Implementation" common to both Java and C#?

Comment: @RPK This is from java perspective.

Answer (score 2):

1. Interface is a fully abstract class,
   Means only signatures, no implementations, no data members.
   On the other hand abstract class by defenition needs at least one abstract method.
   Also it can have implementations. 
   And it also can contain data members which will be inherited to its inheritors.
2. The inheritor needs to implement the abstract method with the same signature in order to implement it

Answer (score 1):

in JAVA Yes,

1. if you use abstract class this way, then there is no difference between interface and abstract class. what dose abstract class really matter is you can offer common implementation which expect to be inherited by sub class, that's interface is not able to do.
2. yes, as I said, that abstract class behave the same way as interface, you can just override the methods in sub class

For example:

```
public abstract class AbstractClassWithoutImplementation {

public abstract String methodA();
```

}

```
public class Implementation extends AbstractClassWithoutImplementation {

@Override
public String methodA() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "Yes";
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Implementation im = new Implementation();
    System.out.println(im.methodA());
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

An abstract class is a class that cannot be instantiated. It is in between a concrete class (fully implemented) and an interface (not at all implemented).

It can contain regular members (variables, methods etc) that are fully implemented.

It can also contain abstract members that are not implemented. Any member that is not implemented, say a method signature, must be marked abstract.

So to answer your questions:

> Like Interfaces, can an abstract class have only method signature without implementation?

Your wording is not clear enough to give a yes or no answer. An abstract class can have implemented methods, and it can have abstract methods that are not implemented which must be marked as `abstract`. It **cannot** have methods without implementation unless they are marked `abstract`.

> If yes: How it differs from Interface?

Because it allows implementation of members.

> How another class, for which this Abstract Class is acting as a base class, can implement the body of that method?

Simply needs to implement all the abstract members.

```
public abstract class A
{ 
    public abstract void Test();
}

public class B : A
{
    public void Test(){ return; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Like Interfaces, can an abstract class have only method signature without implementation? If yes:`

**Yes,** An `abstract` class can have all `abstract` methods even if it has a single abstract method it must be `abstract`.You can declare a class as `abstract` even if it doesn't have any `abstract` method.

`How it differs from Interface?`

In Interface ALL methods are `abstract public` bet in  Abstract class it is not necessary that .Please read about [Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28Java%29) vs [Abstract Class](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2001-04/03-qa-0420-abstract.html)

`How another class, for which this Abstract Class is acting as a base class, can implement the body of that method?`

If your `BaseClass` is Abstract and `ChildClass` is extending Base class you can implement `abstract` method in `ChildClass` otherwise make `ChildClass` `abstrac`t also.

```
public class ChildClass extends BaseClass{

void display(){

    /// Your Implementation here
}

}

abstract class BaseClass{

abstract void display();
}
```